# ajax callback multiple find

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I want to find `#global_content` and `#global_content2` and then display them in `#global_content3`. The function below is working fine with one selector. I am able to do only with `#global_content` but how do I find the second one and display all of them in `#global_content3`?

```
function loadContent() {
    toLoadSelector = '#global_content';

jQuery.ajax({
    url: toLoad,
    success: function(data,status,jqXHR) { 
        data = jQuery(data).find( toLoadSelector );
        jQuery('#global_content3').html(data).fadeIn('fast', hideLoader());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy HTML around. You should be able to do something like:

```
$(data).find('#global_content, #global_content2').appendTo('#global_content3');
```

Haven't tested.